# Image Javascript pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a solution for image pop-up.

The usual image to be enlarged on mouse click. The idea should be something like Highslide pop-up. I'd like to assign the event using CSS.  for example if the img tag has a specific class that image should be enlarged.

Maybe someone has a nice solution.

Comment: You need to try Googling, S.O. is here to answer questions you have about coding, not be a resource for knowledge lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). They have demos on the site and code examples, so you should be able to figure out how to trigger it only on elements wiht a certain class.

```
$('img.someClass').fancybox({/* ..whatever options you want.. */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z8RZ/37/

HTML:

```
<button>bigger</button>
<img class="smaller" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg">
```

JS:

```
     $(document.body).on('click', 'button', function() {         
        $('img').toggleClass('bigger');       
    });​
```

CSS:

```
.smaller{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
.bigger{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}​
```